# iPhone customized view before crash

Tags: iphone, crash

I have a view in my app which says something like "sorry for the crash, please restart the app", and I'd like to show it after crash. so is there any general way I can detect a crash that is about to happen and show the view before it does?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it.  A crash is a crash.  The best you could do is wrap @try/catch around your code in main.m, but I wouldn't recommend it and it wouldn't catch serious errors.  iPhone users recognize crashes when the apps go away.  I'm willing to bet that showing a special view for a crash would be even more annoying to users, as if you so expect a crash you even made a screen! ;-)  Users will grow to hate that screen.

What *is* recommend is to capture the crash and then the next time the user runs the app, you can say "We see your app has crashed" and perhaps send a dump of the stack trace to yourself so you can see what happened.  You can handle the crashes by defining this method in your app delegate:

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    // save exception to file
}
```

And call this method in your didFinishLaunching method:

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
```

Next time they start the app, check for that file and if it exists, send it.

Answer (score 1):

Can recommend this [Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com) blog [post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html). It has a sample project you can learn from too.